# How can I compute the conditional mean, given a standard deviation?

Tags: expected-value, standard-deviation, constraints

Suppose that I have knowledge of a population's mean and standard deviation. Then, new information is provided to constrain the draw of the next sample to be at least a certain value: the value is `>= min_value`. What is the expected value for the next sample, given this constraint?

(I'm using Python, in case anyone has a solution involving scipy, etc).

Update: please assume a normal distribution.

Comment: If all you have is the mean and standard deviation and you know nothing else about the functional form of the distribution, then at best you can have is very loose bounds (inequality) for such a conditional mean. Knowing it being unimodal and symmetric helps only very little.

Comment: Thanks. What if we assume a normal distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, and let $l$ be the lower bound of this next sample. Given the constraint, and using the identity $\phi '(x)\equiv -x\phi (x)$, the expected value is \begin{align*}
\mathbb E(X|X>l)&=\mu +\sigma\,\mathbb E\left(Z|Z>l'\right)=\mu +\sigma \cdot \frac{\int _{l'}^\infty x\phi (x)\,{\rm d}x}{1-\Phi(l')}\\
&=\mu+\sigma\cdot \frac{-\int_{l'}^\infty \phi'(x)\,{\rm d}x}{1-\Phi(l')}=\mu +\frac{\sigma\phi(l')}{1-\Phi(l')}
\end{align*}
where $Z\sim N(0,1)$, $l'=\frac{l-\mu}{\sigma}$, $\phi(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ is the p.d.f. of the standard normal distribution, and $\Phi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x\phi(z)\,{\rm d}z$ is the c.d.f. of the standard normal distribution.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.expect.html

...might be a sufficient answer (assuming I know the distribution) for anyone using scipy, but an analytical solution would be welcome.